# SQLAlchemy - Postgres: using with_entities for querying JSON element

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query for a field in JSON column (Postgres):

```
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    data = Column(JSONB)
```

Query:

```
my_query = session.query(MyTable).limit(10).with_entities(MyTable.data['rule']).all()
```

I get no error, but the result is empty.

Even if I try with `astext`, same empty result:

```
my_query = session.query(MyTable).limit(10).with_entities(MyTable.data['rule'].astext).all()
```

Can I use with_entities in this case? What would be the work around?
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the `['rule']` part be on the result, not in the with_entities field?

Comment: @Paul Becotte: I do not think so. Otherwise, the whole purpose of accessing JSON fields from the query is lost.

Comment: It works for me. (`session.add(MyTable(data={"rule": "foo"})); session.flush(); session.query(MyTable)...`)  Perhaps you don't have any rows in your table?

Comment: @univerio: I do, in fact when I query for another non-JSON column I get results. Could you post what your my_query[0] look like?

Comment: `(u'foo',)`. When you say the result is empty, `my_query` is the empty list?

Comment: Yes, if I query only for JSON field I get an empty dictionary for my_query[0].

Comment: That's not the empty list. It means your JSON field has the data `{"rule": {}}`.

Comment: @univerio: If I print out the sqlalchemy query, it does not query for rule at all: `SELECT my_table.data -> :data_1 ...`, I wonder could you print the query?

Comment: `:data_1` is a parameter that's bound to `'rule'`. `a -> 'foo'` is the syntax for accessing JSON fields.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution. The 'rule' data was actually read, however I could not access it by `my_query.rule` as the `'rule'` member was never there. What helped is adding `label()` method: `my_query = session.query(MyTable).limit(10).with_entities(MyTable.data['rule'].label('rule')).all()`

Answer (score 1):

The addition of `label()` method solved the issue for me:

```
my_query = session.query(MyTable).limit(10). \
        with_entities(MyTable.data['rule'].label('rule')).all()
```